# Tow way for call a action in asp.net mvc with route attribute - Routing In asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, razorengine

All 
i want 2 way for call a action . for example

```
http://localhost:16800/Content1/1/text
```

and

```
 http://localhost:16800/Content1/1
```

and my routeconfig is default routeing. i use from route attribute .

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and my controller used route attribute so :

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
```

{

```
 [RoutePrefix("Content1")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class Content1Controller : Controller
{

    [Route("{id}/{text}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string text)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

}
Now , this way working for me . **`http://localhost:16800/Content1/1/text`**

and this way not working for me. **`http://localhost:16800/Content1/1`**
i just to use both way for call my action.
Remind that i use `[Route("{action=Index}")]` on the my controller i don,t need define Action name in my url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this, It will work(tested).


namespace WebApplicationExamples.Controllers
    {
        [RoutePrefix("Content1")]
        [Route("{action=Index}")]
        public class Content1Controller : Controller
        {

            // GET: Content1
            [Route("{id}")]
            [Route("{id}/{text}")]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i test your code in a test project . and this work fine. but it,s not work my main project. :(

Comment: i get this error A public action method '1' was not found on controller

Comment: oh. i  use HttpGet and this work fine.[Route("{id}")]
        [Route("{id}/{title}")]
        [HttpGet]